# How to predict probabilities in xgboost using R?

Tags: machine-learning, r, predictive-modeling, decision-trees, xgboost

The below predict function is giving -ve values as well so it cannot be probabilities.

```
param <- list(max.depth = 5, eta = 0.01,  objective="binary:logistic",subsample=0.9)
bst <- xgboost(param, data = x_mat, label = y_mat,nround = 3000)

pred_s <- predict(bst, x_mat_s2)
```

I google & tried `pred_s <- predict(bst, x_mat_s2,type="response")`
but it didn't work.

**Question**

How to predict probabilities instead?

Comment: Doesn't it output probabilities by default with the settings you used? I mean: have you examined pred_s and you are certain those are not probabilities?

Comment: No its having negative values. Probability should vary between 0 to 1.

Comment: I don't see any obvious issues. (Although, I'm more familiar with the python wrapper). Have you tried adding `outputmargin=F` to the `predict` function? If somehow the `outputmargin` is set to `T`, it will return the value before the logistic transformation.

Comment: For Python, you can copy `predict_proba` implementation from `sklearn` API: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/python-package/xgboost/sklearn.py#L534

Answer (score 22):

Just use `predict_proba` instead of `predict`. You can leave the objective as `binary:logistic`.

Comment: If this were Python and not R, then this answer might be sensible. Wrong language.

Comment: oops! thanks @B_Miner. I'm not deleting this answer as it might be helpful for others that will make the same mistake and think we're talking about python..

Comment: For me this does not do the trick http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/14527/xgboost-predict-probabilities

Comment: xgboost does not have a predict_proba function

Comment: XGBoost Classifier does has a predict_proba option https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html

Comment: I made the same mistake of assuming this question was about Python. And i found my solution because someone else made the same mistake and answered the question. So upvoting the answer. Is something wrong with stackoverflow? Just wondering...

Comment: This is a common misconception and it really depends on what you mean by probability. The default output using the "binary:logistic" objective is a classification score. Not a probability. A prediction is assigned to either class by e.g. >=0.5 == 1.

Now a true probability, a binomial for instance, you require the 'multi:softprob' objective as as outlined in @cyber0g answer [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/8812/47485)

Answer (score 17):

Know I'm a bit late, but to get probabilities from `xgboost` you should specify `multi:softmax` objective like this:

```
xgboost(param, data = x_mat, label = y_mat,nround = 3000, objective='multi:softprob')
```

From the `?xgb.train`:

> multi:softprob same as softmax, but output a vector of ndata * nclass, which can be further reshaped to ndata, nclass matrix. The result contains predicted probabilities of each data point belonging to each class.

Comment: Thanks. How is this loss function different from binary:logistic for binary classification?

Comment: It's just a generalization of logistic function for multi-class case, should be no significant difference.

Comment: I used it and it worked well, but I had an issue. I'm facing a warning "Parameters: { scale_pos_weight } might not be used.", which comes form the fact I use multi:softprob ([source](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/5717#issuecomment-634621557)). Why my unbalanced data, it seems that this param is really important (if I go for a classic binary classification), and currently, when I change it, it has no impact because it's not taken into account.

Answer (score 3):

After the prediction:

```
pred_s <- predict(bst, x_mat_s2)
```

You can get the probability by:

```
pred_s$data
```

If this is a binary classification
then `pred_s$data` includes prob.0, prob.1, response.

So you can get prob.1 by:

```
pred_s$data$prob.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Many years late, but noticed this; and this is how I do it:

`pred_s <- predict(bst, x_mat_s2, type="prob")`

Typically then I then work with probability of my upper class "1":

```
pred_s[,2]
```