# Xgboost predict probabilities

Tags: predictive-modeling, scikit-learn, xgboost, probability

When using the python / sklearn API of xgboost are the probabilities obtained via the `predict_proba` method "real probabilities" or do I have to use `logit:raw`and manually calculate the sigmoid function?

I wanted to experiment with different cutoff points. Currently using `binary:lgistic`via the `sklearn:XGBClassifier` the probabilities returned from the `prob_a` method rather resemble 2 classes and not a continuous function where changing the cut-off point impacts the final scoring.

Is this the right way to obtain probabilities for experimenting with the cutoff value?

[image]

Comment: Same question, I want to figure out if the predict_proba works too. Do you know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LightGBM forum was the answer ;) https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/issues/272#issuecomment-276168493

- apparently, my model is fitting the result very good, i.e. it is very sure about the class probabilities
- I did not expect such clear-cut boundaries and thus was confused if this could be correct.

Comment: Can you please summarize the main points from that article?  If the link stops working, this answer will become useless.  Also, we don't want to be just a link farm pointing to other places.  (See also http://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers.)  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Curious Georg if you ran across [this article](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/03/complete-guide-parameter-tuning-xgboost-with-codes-python/) in your pursuit of trying to generate probabilities. It is worth noting that `binary:logistic` and `multi:softprob` return predicted probability of each data point belonging to each class.

You can look [here](https://gist.github.com/slaypni/b95cb69fd1c82ca4c2ff) to see how the following code is used:
[image: XGBoost Predict_Proba Code]

Comment: Still the output does not look like probabilities. https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/1763 in the jvm version it seems to work better